# Create a list with all sentences from a text

Tags: python, regex

How can I create a list with all sentences, where a sentence needs to have at least 3 words, from a text. The sentences are split by `".?!"`.
For example:

```
text = "Hi! How are you? I am fine."
```

The list will be: `["How are you", "I am fine"]`

Comment: what have you tried? can you share your code? thanks

Comment: i would suggest using https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html or https://spacy.io/api/sentencizer for basics, senetnce spliting is not as simple as re.split as there are a lot of false positive cases. checkout https://www.grammarly.com/blog/engineering/how-to-split-sentences/

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
import re

txt = "Hi! How are you? I am fine."
print([i[0].strip() for i in re.findall(r"((\W\w+){3,}(?=(\.|\!|\?)))", txt)])
```

Output

```
['How are you', 'I am fine']
```

This regex is extracting from a given string all three words or more that separated by . or ! or ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` function with regex.

```py
import re

s_nums = 'Hi! How are you? I am fine.'

print([sen for sen in re.split('\.|!|\?', s_nums) if len(sen) > 2])
```

Comment: "a sentence needs to have at least 3 words"

Comment: you can add a simple check after this for atleast 3 words but the major issue is it splits wrong when there is a sentece like "Good morning, said Mr. ABC in the morning." which will give you "Good morning, said Mr" and "ABC in the morning" but thats wrong

Comment: @cerofrais you are right. But i do not came up with a solution better than defining all abbreviations explicitly. It is not practical.

Comment: that's why I was suggesting go for ML based sentence tokenizers which can do better generalizations